# launch other launch files and ROS nodes

Tags: ros, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to ROS and the launch file syntax is scary. I want to launch all of these together:

-roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

-roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo gmapping_demo.launch

-roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch

-roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_t...

-rosbag record -a

My question is: Can a launch file do this? or how would i go about making this executable by typing in "roslaunch .launch" into a terminal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239070/launch-other-launch-files-and-ros-nodes/) by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To launch all together you have simply to include all the launch files into a single launch file. (Take a look to [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects) ).

Regarding the rosbag check this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/62811/how-to-play-rosbag-using-launch-file/), the xml syntax for `rosbag record -a`is: `<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="recorder" output="screen" args="-a"/>`  (in "args" you can put all the arguments for that command)

So the whole launch file to launch all you need is:

```
<launch>

   <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/turtlebot_world.launch"/>
   <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/gmapping_demo.launch"/>
   <include file="$(find turtlebot_rviz_launchers)/launch/view_robot.launch"/>
   <include file="$(find turtlebot_teleop)/launch/keyboard_t.launch"/>

   <!-- 
     The rosbag will be saved in the ~./ros folder
   -->
   <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="recorder" output="screen" args="-a"/>    
</launch>
```

Now you can launch it from the terminal as a normal launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) with karma: 113 on 2016-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on 2016-07-08**:
This was a more helpful answer than I expected! Thanks for the links as well as the xml example! :)

**Comment by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on 2016-07-08**:
One more question: I need to somehow link my launch file to somewhere so that I don't have to be in the launch directory to launch it. I believe I learned how to do this in the tutorials, but as I'm searching through them again I don't see it. I'm gonna keep looking, but help would be appreciated.

**Comment by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) on 2016-07-08**:
You can launch it from whatever folder you are in, just type:

```
roslaunch <name_package> file.launch
```

If you use `roslaunch file.launch` you have to be in the launch folder of the package.

I am not completely understing your question, is this what you mean?

**Comment by [Morefoam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27425/morefoam/) on 2016-07-08**:
I figured it out. Thanks for the help. I have another question, though. Is there a way to make the bag file save to a specified folder? How do I change "" to make it save to a specified location?

**Comment by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) on 2016-07-09**:
  `<arg name="FOLDER" default="/home/nicola/test/"/>  <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="recorder" output="screen" args="-a -o $(arg FOLDER)"/>`

**Comment by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) on 2016-07-09**:
The "arg" stuff is like creating a variable. When you launch the file you can pass the name of the folder as parameter (roslaunch name_package launnch_file FOLDER:=new_folder) otherwise it will use the one specified in the default tag. See [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline) for more opts